# findResourceById() returning null

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-button

I've read a few questions and answers regarding this topic, but none of them applied to my issue.

My problem is in the following code:

```
 public class Activity2 extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alt);

}


public void buttonPress(View v){
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    if((tv1 != null) & (tv2 != null) & (b1 != null)){
        tv1.setText(R.string.changed);
        tv2.setText(R.string.changed);
        b1.setText(R.string.changed);
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "VIEW ELEMENTS ARE NOT BEING ASSIGNED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

alt.xml looks like this

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:name="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stuff" />

<TextView
    android:name="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stuff2" />

<Button
    android:name="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buttonText"
    android:onClick="buttonPress" />
```

The IDs are being generated in R.id, but they aren't being assigned to my two TextView elements and my one Button element. (I'm seeing the toast popup every time)

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Did you mean to write `&&` instead of `&`?

Comment: @EboMike yes, thanks, fixed it and same problem though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `android:name="..."` use `android:id="@+id/..."`

Comment: Tried this to no avail. The IDs are being generated so I don't think they're the problem.

Comment: I take that back, I was trying this with the changes another person had suggested and then deleted. After reverting back, this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
android:name="@+id/text1"
```

By

```
android:id="@+id/text1"
```